# Network Latency When AirDrop is Active on Another Device

Tags: macos, network, wifi, bluetooth

I've been trying to find the root cause of this for days. It started off when I noticed stutters during a WebRTC video session, so I started an internal ping to my main router (note: I use Unifi with a UDM-Pro).

Once in a while I'd see huge spikes in latency, like below:
[image: high ping to router]

It was extremely random, though I noticed that it wouldn't happen while I had bluetooth turned off which was extremely weird, since I was connected over a 5GHz network, so there shouldn't be any channel interference there.

Anyway, after a couple days, I noticed it happen again when my friend airdropped something to his Mac from his phone, so I asked him to do it again and it actually happened when he just opened the share menu on his phone, not even needing to actually airdrop anything, so I assumed it must be something to do with the airdrop protocol over LAN, but nope! It even happened while he had wifi disabled completely.

I've uploaded a short 10 second video of it happening in action here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EQC1YR1NG_0 (same video but with wifi disabled on an iPhone 12 Pro: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jRHtnVRmLB0)

This is seriously the weirdest issue I've experienced - is it something to do with the U1 chip frequency?

**System info:**
MacBook: M1 MacBook Pro 13inch
iOS Device: Tested with iPhone 12 Pro & iPad Pro 2020

Comment: Do you have video or photos of both of your friends devices with WiFi disabled you could add?

Comment: @Scottmeup Done! (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jRHtnVRmLB0)

Comment: I'm wondering if the iPhone's WiFi is disabled vs off, I don't see that in the video. You can tell by looking in Control Centre. I don't see your friends Mac's WiFi settings in the shot either.

Comment: @Scottmeup Ah okay yes, it doesn't happen when wifi is off completely because airdrop doesn't work without it, but I can confirm that the iOS device wasn't connected to the network during the time the video was taken. (also: Mac wifi was on)

Comment: You might be able to confirm this with wireshark, but this sounds very much to me like the airdrop service broadcasting over wifi in order to facilitate discovery of other airdrop compatible devices. If this is the case, there's a reasonable chance that it would cause latency on other devices.

Comment: @Scottmeup Can't see any network activity on the en0 related to Airdrop

Comment: It sounds like the traffic is not being sent across the same WiFi network but is being sent on a channel close enough to your network to cause interference.

Comment: @Scottmeup I've just managed to get my friend who has an M1 mac (in a separate country) to reproduce the issue I have. He's testing using an iPhone 12 Pro too (no rep so can't comment here; I'm commenting for him). He can also confirm that he sees network latency iOS-device side too (https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/820153634338635787/855295141003001856/unknown.png)

Comment: That would be consistent with interference. I don't know enough about Airdrop's implementation to give you a definitive answer but it shows signs of being interference related to a discovery broadcast.

Comment: @Scottmeup Interference sounds plausible, though it doesn't effect the network of any non-Apple device, or any Apple device with bluetooth disabled - I'm just confused as to why I can't find anything online about this issue (it seems pretty big?).

Comment: I'd only be speculating but that sounds like part of the broadcast is done via bluetooth, and involves a wifi-response (or processing of wifi packets) from apple devices that pick it up. It could be something as simple as a bluetooth message that when received by devices with AirDrop capability tells them to:`switch wifi to channel x and respond if this device is on your contact list`